# Find Email from URL link

Tags: email

I have a url link of a company. I need to find all email address of this company. Which is the easy way to find their email address by using url.

Comment: Don't you think spammers would love this easy way?

Answer (score 6):

Not possible. There's nothing connecting a random URL to some global directory of e-mail addresses assigned to that domain. Or for the company, for that matter: some companies don't even use their "public" domain name for e-mail purposes.

The best you could do here is to scrape the site for any e-mail addresses in its content, but that would only provide the ones they *want* people to have, not "all." (Why do you want do to this, anyway?)

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to do a [whois](http://www.whois.net/) lookup and hope that they registered an email address publicly. Other than that, @Su's response is your only other option.

Answer (score 1):

Search google with the following query, note that the `"` are important as is there being no space between the `:` and the domain.

Emails listed on their site:

```
"@domain.com" site:domain.com
```

Emails listed on other sites (results for this are a little sporadic)

```
"@domain.com"
```

You can also try http://www.outreachr.com as well as the other methods outlined above.